# Adding two instance variables containing a name and account number?

Tags: java, string, instance-variables

Im an absolute beginner in java and need help adding a string instance variable. I dont even really know how to ask my question but

```
public class Account {
  private int AccountNumber;
  private int FirstName;
  private int LastName;
// ok here is where im stuck, i realize that Firstname and LastName are not integers but how else can i make a instance variable of them?           
  private double balance;
 public Account(double initialBalance, int getFirstName, int getLastName, int        getAccountNumber) {
//Int is not the correct type for FirstName and LastName but I dont know what else to call it. Any ideas?
    FirstName = getFirstName;
    LastName = getLastName;
    AccountNumber = getAccountNumber;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `String`? Start by going through [this tutorial on Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Answer (score 0):

You want `String` parameter types for your `String` fields:

```
 public Account(double initialBalance, String firstName, String lastName, int accountNumber) {
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    AccountNumber = accountNumber;
}
```

Perhaps you were thinking of C style pointers, which java doesn't have.

Comment: Compilation error, as the declaration is:  private int AccountNumber;

Answer (score 0):

As Sotirios mentioned, use String like this-

```
public class Account {
  private int AccountNumber;
  private String FirstName;
  private String LastName;
  private double balance;
  public Account(double initialBalance, String getFirstName, String getLastName, int getAccountNumber) {
   FirstName = getFirstName;
   LastName = getLastName;
   AccountNumber = getAccountNumber;
  }
}
```

Comment: @BillySims If your issue was resolved, do close the thread by accepting a answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Account {
  private int accountNumber;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private double balance;
  public Account(double aInitialBalance, String aFirstName, String aLastName, int        aAccountNumber) {
    balance =aInitialBalance;
    firstName = aFirstName;
    lastName = aLastName;
    accountNumber = aAccountNumber;
 }
}

class  AccountTest{

 public static void main(String []args){
    Account a1=new Account(100.00,"Billy","Sims",1);
    System.out.println("FirstNmae:"+a1.firstName);
    System.out.println("LastNmae:"+a1.lastName);
    System.out.println("Balance:"+a1.balance);
    System.out.println("AccountNumber:"+a1.accountNumber);
 }
}
```